# Is there a medrash that says that foxes and fish lived together?

Tags: midrash, allegory-mashal

In [Brachos 61b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.61b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) there is the famous parable of a fox trying to get the fish do go on the land.
As part of the trick, the fox says:

> וְנָדוּר אֲנִי וְאַתֶּם, כְּשֵׁם שֶׁדָּרוּ אֲבוֹתַי עִם אֲבוֹתֵיכֶם
>
> and we will reside together just as my ancestors resided with your ancestors

Is there any medrash that says that foxes and fish did live together at one point?

Comment: You just quoted one.

Comment: @Alex that is a gemara.

Comment: So you are specifically looking for non-Gemara sources? Are those more authoritative?

Comment: Do you mean like the Midrash of the theory of the evolution of the species?

Comment: Agav: See Bechoros 8a, Fish and Fox can't have offspring together. Perhaps that was the intention of the Fox. See there.